On Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Pi 4 how to install / run VNC server?
I would like to remote control my signed in session in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my Pi4. Using the Remote Desktop seems not the right replacement for remote controlling an existing session like VNC server (which is not bundled anymore in 24.04).
So now it seems Ubuntu 24.04 LTS does not have a built in VNC server anymore (I am not sure, that's why I am asking), I am trying to install my own VNC server.
I tried to install vnc server such as tigervncserver but I cannot start the server because some kind of service already running:
A X11 server is already running for display :1 on machine pi4.

How can I get my VNC server running (does not have to be tigervnc but whatever works)?

I would highly recommend NoMachine since you are on a Pi 4. Also, this might be helpful but I'm not entirely sure. :^)
